# Function to return contents of a specific string

Tags: c#, string

It is possible for a function to read/return the value of a string whose name is passed to it?

For example, I want to return true if the value of a string is not "0" by telling the function which string I want it to check.

```
public static bool IsEnabled(string sName)
{
    if (TenderTypes.<sName> != "0")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is mainly to make things quicker while I'm coding, I want to be able to keep the strings there but at the same time I want to be able to disable them by changing their value from a string number, to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have something like this:

```
class TenderTypes
{
    static string myStr = "Some value";
    static string anotherStr = "A different value";
    // ...
};
```

And you want to query that string by the name of a field (for example `"myStr"`).

Well, it can be done with reflection. But first an alternative:

---

### Using a Dictionary

```
class TenderTypes
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> strings =
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"myStr", "Some value},
        {"anotherStr", "Some value}
    }
    //...
}
```

Then you could write your method like this:

```
public static bool IsEnabled(string sName)
{
    if (TenderTypes.strings[sName] != "0")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

### Using Reflection

Then you could write your method like this:

```
public static bool IsEnabled(string sName)
{
    var type = typeof(TenderTypes);
    var field = type.GetField(sName, BindingFlags.Static);
    if (field.GetValue(null) != "0")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to use the reflection method as I already use `TenderTypes.name` for other bits that cant be changed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want to achieve, your syntax looks like you are trying to query something generic `<>`... this is not really possible.

Maybe a simple [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will help you?

Create a `new Dictionary<string, bool>` should also help you if your "settings" are enabled or disabled...